# How can I copy one array to another in C and get two separate arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, copy

I need to copy an array to another, then change copied array without affecting the original one.
I tried:

`memcpy(statesVactor,denominatorFactors,n *sizeof(int));`
and
`memmove(statesVector,denominatorFactors,n *sizeof(int));`

But still when I multiply statesVector by -1, denominatorFactors multiplies as well.
I feel, I don't understand sth simple.

EDIT:

```
int n = 0; 
int denominatorFactors[n];
int statesVector[n];
 scanf("%d", &n);
memmove(statesVector,denominatorFactors,n *sizeof(int)); //or 
//memcpy(statesVactor,denominatorFactors,n *sizeof(int)); 

for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        statesVector[i] = -1 * statesVector[i];
    }

for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        printf("%d\t",statesVector[i]);
    }
for(int i = 0; i<n;i++) {
         printf("%d",denominatorFactors[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you sure you allocated 2 arrays instead of doing like `int statesVactor[n]; int* denominatorFactors = statesVactor;`?

Comment: I added more code. I hope it's better. I am really not sure what I am doing. I've always used Java, it's my first project in C and everythig is...different. I think I did what you suggested I shouldn't.

Comment: Allocating zero-element array like `int n = 0; int denominatorFactors[n];` is not allowed. The number of elements of array must be greater than zero. (reference: paragraph 5 of [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.7.6.2 Array declarators)

Comment: You're right, my bad. Forgot to add scanf("%d", &n);

Comment: Reading of `n` must be before the declarations of arrays. Also the elements of `statesVector` should be initialized before the loop, of *undefined behavior* will be invoked by using values of uninitialized non-static local variables, which are indeterminate.

Comment: I changed everything as you suggested and I think it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize the size of array at 0 (int n = 0; int denominatorFactors[n])

You declarate your array after you read the size not before

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int size;
    do
    {
         printf("Give the size of your array :");
         scanf("%d",&size);
    }while(size <1);
    int statesVector[size];
    int denominatorFactors[size];
    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("Give me the %d elment :",i);
        scanf("%d",&statesVector[i]);
        denominatorFactors[i] = statesVector[i];
    }
    printf("\n\nDisplay of the original array :\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("[%d]\t",statesVector[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nDisplay of the copy of array :\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
        denominatorFactors[i]*=-1;
        printf("[%d]\t",denominatorFactors[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```